# ubuntu does not boot and get stuck on the logo

Tags: lenovo

I have a Lenovo Helix 2 and I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on it. Most of the time after booting in the Ubuntu logo stage, when there is a rotating circle, it gets stuck and the circle keeps spinning and Linux does not come up. I have to restart it with the power button.
The graphics of this lab are Intel.
What to do with this bug?

Comment: Is this an official Ubuntu 20.04, or something else? Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: I've done what you said @heynnema . The picture is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/wisk8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

Lenovo Helix 2

You have BIOS version GFET55WW (1.34).

There's a newer BIOS available. Depending on your exact model #, you'll find:

For **Helix (Type 20CG, 20CH) Laptop (ThinkPad)**, BIOS version 2.12 can be downloaded from [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-helix-series-laptops/thinkpad-helix-type-20cg-20ch/downloads/ds101505).

For **Helix (Type 3xxx) Laptop (ThinkPad)**, BIOS version 1.44 can be downloaded from [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-helix-series-laptops/thinkpad-helix-type-3xxx/downloads/ds034627).

Note: Confirm your model # to know what BIOS to download.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: I updated the bios to 1.44 but it didn't help. the bus still exist. I have to add nomodeset after quick splash words at the ubuntu boot page then ubuntu comes up.

Comment: @ZaniarGhaderi Ah! That's a good clue that there may be a problem with your video driver. Do you have Nvidia? What model # and driver version?

Comment: No my graphic driver isn't nvidia. It's intel hd graphics 4000

Comment: @ZaniarGhaderi Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: @ZaniarGhaderi Status please...

Comment: I updated the bios and reinstall the ubuntu after windows installation on the same laptop. now it doesn't have any problem and runs well. I just haven't updated the ubuntu. I think problems appears after the updates.

Comment: my laptop also had a problem with windows. its touch screen doesn't works usually. but after updating the bios that problem is solved. thank you for that @heynnema